# How chrome extenstion can save Command Line "monitorEvents" output through devtools_page api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I send a message to the background page from the devtools page，if eval script has a result,bg page can receive the msg ,but if Command Line like "monitorEvents",it just 'undefined'.

[image]

Is there a way to get all the results？

```js
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
  "inspect(monitorEvents(window,'click'))",
  function(result, isException) { 
log(isException);
backgroundPageConnection.postMessage({
    name: 'init',
data:result,
    tabId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId
});
}
);
```

Comment: monitorEvents doesn't have any result, it directly prints to console, so you'll have to intercept it by using chrome.debugger API, but that's a heavy hammer.